# java -AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread is taking more cpu time

Tags: java, mysql

My app is reading data from csv and  insert into mysql.its taking more cpu.

When I debugged below jdbc thread is taking more cpu.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:40)
```

Centos,

1.top

```
7435 root      20   0 7677556 366436  14528 S  86.4  4.8  67:05.60 java
```

2. top

```
top -n 1 -H -p 7435
top - 15:48:23 up 57 days, 21 min, 11 users,  load average: 0.47, 0.53, 0.62
Threads:  28 total,   1 running,  27 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  4.9 us,  3.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 91.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  7650496 total,   188012 free,  1122392 used,  6340092 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16777212 total, 16775664 free,     1548 used.  5914108 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 7595 root      20   0 7677556 345864  14528 R 60.0  4.5 142:04.27 java
 7435 root      20   0 7677556 345864  14528 S  0.0  4.5   0:00.00 java
 7436 root      20   0 7677556 345864  14528 S  0.0  4.5   0:01.24 java
 7454 root      20   0 7677556 345864  14528 S  0.0  4.5   1:06.92 java
 7459 root      20   0 7677556 345864  14528 S  0.0  4.5   1:07.11 java
```

any idea?

```
ExecutorService service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(count);
            FileAlterationObserver fao = new FileAlterationObserver(folder);
            fao.addListener(new FileListener(service));
            final FileAlterationMonitor monitor = new FileAlterationMonitor(Integer.parseInt("100"));
            monitor.addObserver(fao);
            monitor.start();
```

Whenever listner recived csv i am submitting to the Excutor service

```
service.submit(new PerformanceFileReader(f));
```

Comment: This not reproducible in windows its only in linux type os

Comment: If you properly close the `Connection` objects in the code there is no need for `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread`. That's why some pools simply don't have this feature e.g. [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).

Comment: I am properly closing all the connection